# How to map enums to integers

Tags: java

I have an enum class

```
public enum PacketTypes {
        NONE,  //0
        TEXT, //1
        ACCEL, //2
        GYRO,  //3
        MAG,   //4
        LOCATION, //5
        QUAT, //6
        COLOR, //7
        BUTTON //8
    }
```

I'm curious how to map these enums to ints, e.g.

```
    System.out.println(PacketTypes.LOCATION); // Prints a 5
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: `System.out.println(PacketTypes.LOCATION.ordinal());`

Comment: Does this help?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Why do you want to treat your enum values like integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`ordinal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) method that comes with enums:

```
System.out.println(PacketTypes.LOCATION.ordinal());
```

You can also go the other way:

```
int typeIndex = 3;
PacketTypes type = PacketTypes.values()[typeIndex]; // GYRO
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override your toString method if you want that exact functionality whilst maintaining your own set of integers :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
 switch (name()) {
  case TEXT: return "1";
  case ACCEL: return "2";
         ...
  default: return "0";
 }
}
```

Of course you will need a name() method if you don't already have one.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Ted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529608/how-to-map-enums-to-integers/43529642#43529642)'s answer, if you want to iterate through your enum, use `values()`

```
for (PacketTypes packet : PacketTypes.values()) {
     System.out.println(packet);
 }
```

Or access a particular element by `PacketTypes.values()[indexOfElement]`

Answer (score 0):

This is also helpful

```
int index = Arrays.asList(PacketTypes.values()).indexOf(PacketTypes. LOCATION);
```